# Kafka streams application is still trying to create changelog topic though i am setting the optimization property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Below is the code snippet i am using,

`streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-live-test");
 streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "brokerIP:port");
 streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(**StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE**);

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();
KStream streamData = builder.stream(inputTopicName);

streamData.groupByKey(Grouped.with(jsonSerde,jsonSerde))
.aggregate(
      //some transformation
);

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(streamConfiguration),streamConfiguration);
`

i check the confluent page for optimization method and followed the suggested changes. but still it is trying to generate changelogTopic.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your confusion here, but the optimization for changelog topics is only for ***source `KTable`*** operations.  For example:

```java
KTable<String, String> someTable = builder.table("topic");
```

With optimizations turned on, then Kafka Streams will use source topic for the `KTable` as the changelog topic as well.

If you don't want Kafka Streams to create a changelog topic for your aggregation then you'll need to explicitly disable it with `Materialized.withLoggingDisabled()` config object:

```java
streamData.groupByKey(Grouped.with(jsonSerde,jsonSerde)) .aggregate(initializer, aggregator, Materialized.as("store-name").withLoggingDisabled();
```

The above is just one example; you can also use [`Materialized`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html) to configure the key and value `Serdes` if required.  But the bottom line is to prevent changelog topics you need to use `Materialized.withLoggingDisabled()`.

Additionally, you can configure changelog topics using the [`StoreBuilder`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/StoreBuilder).  The Javadoc for [`Stores`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores) has a brief example of using a `StoreBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Note: if you enable optimization, and a source KTable changelog topic is not created, the source topic is used to provide fault-tolerance. In contrast, if you disable logging as describe in the answer, you disable fault-tolerance for the corresponding KTable! Disabling changelogging is not an optimization but changes your fault-tolerance guarantees!